# Replacing Strings using Loops in Python

Tags: python, string, loops, replace

I'm still new to Python and I've had a hard time on how to Loop this.

```
mynewvar2=varlist3.replace('R0','_0').replace('R1','_1').replace('R2','_2').replace('R3','_3').replace('R4','_4').replace('R5','_5').replace('R6','_6').replace('R7','_7').replace('R8','_8').replace('R9','_9')
```

The problem here is that I'm gonna add many .replace() functions if I'm given more than that.

Thank you so much for your help guys!

Comment: are you always replacing the same character `'R'` with `'_'`? then possibly do `mynewvar2 = varlist3.replace('R', '_')`, should yield the same result, but many possible solutions. depends on specific input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: s = 'XR0R1R2R3'

In [2]: before = ['R0','R1','R2','R3']

In [3]: after = ['_0','_1','_2','_3']

In [4]: for a, b in zip(before, after):
   ...:     s = s.replace(a, b)
   ...:     

In [5]: s
Out[5]: 'X_0_1_2_3'
```

Comment: also , if you have many before and after like R0 ...to...R101, you can use range function to build it, save typing.